# xs={false} or xs={0} does not work in MUI React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a code here for the video and login page template. However, as you can see it does not work? It goes to the top of the login page. When I was using a picture, it disappeared as stated. How can I force xs={} setting?

```
<Grid container component='main' className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Grid item xs={false} sm={4} md={9}>
        <BackgroundVideo />
      </Grid>
      <Grid
        item
        xs={12}
        sm={8}
        md={3}
        component={Paper}
        elevation={6}
        square
        className={classes.formBackground}
      >
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`xs={false}` means that there is no breakpoint, so it doesn't change sizing at this breakpoint. `false` is a default value for all breakpoints.

You can hide `Grid` item by wrapping it with a `Box` component.

```
<Box
  component={Grid}
  item
  sm={4} 
  md={9}
  display={{ xs: "none", sm: "block" }}
>
  <BackgroundVideo />
</Box>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the answer from [Nikolai Kiselev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5964023/nikolai-kiselev) mentioned, values of `false` or `0` will not hide the grid item.

The way I've been getting around this is by wrapping my grid items in a [`Hidden` component](https://material-ui.com/components/hidden/) like so (using your example as a base):

```
<Grid container component='main' className={classes.root}>
                            <CssBaseline />
                            <Hidden only='xs'>
                                <Grid item xs={false} sm={4} md={9}>
                                    <BackgroundVideo />
                                </Grid>
                            </Hidden>
                            <Grid
                                item
                                xs={12}
                                sm={8}
                                md={3}
                                component={Paper}
                                elevation={6}
                                square
                                className={classes.formBackground}
                            >
```

Make sure to note that if you go with this approach, whatever value you pass in the breakpoints where the component will be hidden (`xs` in this example) will be ignored, since the component will be hidden.